# Wood coat stand help needed

Tags: furniture, wood

I want to build/recreate a design that I like on the internet.

Sciangai Coat Stand

[image: Sciangai Coat Stand]

I can't figure out what mechanism I have to make to hold the woods and been able to screw them and maintain their position.

Do you have any idea what to use in the middle to keep the coat stant at the shape I make it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do you have any idea what to use in the middle to keep the coat stant at the shape I make it?

This is probably similar to one of the ways to make the tri-bolt for Chris Schwarz's [folding camp stool](http://blog.lostartpress.com/2014/01/08/make-your-own-tri-bolt-for-a-folding-stool/), as shown below.

[image: tri-bolt]

Basically, you need a central hub for all of the bolts/screws to connect to, and the stand uses this hub as a pivot point when it spreads out.

If you wanted to make it out of metal, you could buy a section of pipe, cut off a short segment (like 1/2" to 3/4" long) and drill and tap the holes for as many vertical slats as you want.  Thicker pipe is better for this application since you want the bolt to have as many threads engaged as practical.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea how the original is done and I'm just theorising here but I bet that if you used [common wood screws](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2708/are-there-specific-types-of-screws-i-should-use-for-woodworking/2714#2714) (with a plain shank under the head) and they screwed into a central wood block, *not too tightly*, you'd have enough play to be able to rotate each of the spindles.

The problem with this of course is that you'd have visible screw heads which is not at all ideal.

Comment: Looks like the original just countersank the screws and filled the holes with wood plugs.