# How do I stop cracking noises from my pergola?

Tags: wood, outdoor

I have built a pergola on my own about 1.5 years ago and it doesn't stop making those cracking wood noises (like the wood is cracking).

First of all I know I have built the pergola pretty good because I have followed the instruction of a friend who owns a wood business, and the pergola also "passed the test" of a very bad weather with very strong wind and rain this winter.
I examined the pergola and I couldn't see any cracks or broken wood anywhere.

There are 2 kind of noises that I hear, I assume that 1 of the noises comes from the material that lays on top of the wooden pergola, while the other noise comes from the wood itself.

The noises comes mostly when there is a change in the weather, the noises start when the sun comes out and last for about few minutes, they start again when the sun goes away, and so on every day.

At first I assumed its because the wood is new, and I know wood tend to expand and shrink depending the weather, moist and such, but I thought that after a year it would stop, but it doesn't, the noises sounds the same.

I figured the noises come from the small wood bars that lay on top of the "main" frame and not from the frame itself, those wood bars are there just so there would be less sun inside and not for holding the structure together, when we put them on, they were not straight enough, so we had to manually put them in the right place with force to be straight, and I assume because of this I hear the crack sounds because they are trying to bend back to their first form.

1. **Should I be worried? How can I check if I should be worried or not?** While I can't see any big cracks in the wood I know that in most cases it doesn't matter and the wood can break without notice anyway.
2. **How can I stop it?** Is there anything I can do to stop those noises? It happens on a daily basis and it is something that really starts to bother me.

Here are some images:
[image: Wood bars that lay on top of the main frame]
[image: General structure of the frame, and how it sits on the wall]

Comment: I'm not sure this is really something that can be answered by the internet. Not without a lot more build detail at least, and describing sound is tricky. Is that plastic sheeting over the top? That's going to act as a speaker and amplify little sounds. Is it the joins moving? Hard to say. Maybe DIY is more appropriate (https://diy.stackexchange.com/)? Maybe not, since they are going to note the same challenges.

Comment: The fact that it occurs at sun up and sun down suggests thermal expansion and contraction.  The trellis members may be rubbing against the beams.  How many nails are used at each beam/trellis connection?  If one nail/screw is used at the center, then the trellis pieces may be rubbing as their width increases and decreases each day.  Another candidate for the rubbing sound could be wind racking the entire structure.  Do you get daily breezes at those times?

Comment: Jdv, thanks, i sure will contact some expert on my side, but i wanted to check online first for clues.

Comment: @Ashlar, You are right, 1 screw is used on each connection (this is because there is simply no space for another one) also there are specific places where the sounds comes from, I tried to locate the exact wood piece that's making the noise, and came down to 1 trellis that made the cracking sound if it was wiggled a bit. The noise usually come at the morning and its very loud (when sun comes out), and usually in the middle of the day when it starts to be warmer or colder, there is also no noise at all when its windy, like nothing at all.

Comment: First off congrats on your build, that's a very impressive structure to tackle for anyone much less an amateur woodworker. Now you Qs, 1) I doubt it. Movement noises, including creaks that sound like wood cracking, are commonplace in wood structures and generally nothing to worry about. 2) It's possible you may not be able to, but the first step has already been taken and you've narrowed it down to local areas. After finding the source(s) of a creak you then do something to prevent wood rubbing, and here that means trying to tighten up your fasteners. [contd]

Comment: If one or more screw can't tighten down you may be experiencing [bridging](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2708/are-there-specific-types-of-screws-i-should-use-for-woodworking/2714#2714) or the screw hole in the beam may be stripped. Fixes are to withdraw the screw, drill a wider pilot hole in the first piece (so the threads can't engage) then drive the screw back home. In the second case you can pack the hole with wood shavings, cocktail sticks/toothpicks or matchsticks, slivers of plastic carton, or short lengths of thin copper wire before driving the screw back in.

Comment: @Graphus, Thank you, so basically I need to search all the places that make those noises and tight them? this is a little problem because the plastic sheet is above the trellis, I don't have access to those screws and I can't really add any more without taking it apart (which i really don't want to). What if i'll add a little wood glue to the sides of the trellis? that might help?

Comment: Tightening the screws would be the no.1 fix and really the best thing to try first. I'm not a contractor but I'm sure that's what one would advise since it's sort of standard for creaks. If you can somehow get glue into any gaps that might also help, no guarantee, but tricky to do consistently and I fear that you risk making a mess and then end up without it fixing the issue. So maybe try it in one or two spots just to see if it seems to help a little? How to get the glue in though..... the best method may be to inject with a glue syringe (available on Amazon if you can't find a local source).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much guys, you helped me a lot!

Comment: We have drilled larger holes , but there is still a lot of thermal expansion noise.
Will it ever stop ? Driving me nuts!!

Comment: @Julie I think i figured the issue, at least on my side, the end of the large beams along the structure were cut at the end toward the open, and were only painted, I took a look into it, and noticed they were all cracked, I think the cracks traveled along the beam and thats why I heard the noises in the middle, I then took some simple wood glue, mixed it with wood dust, and applied it to each beam to close those cracks, I didn't hear any noises in a while now.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this noise is created due to thermal expansion. The roofing screws for polycarbonate sheeting should have a big enough flexible washer so that you can pre drill a hole in the sheeting around twice the diameter of the screw to allow for movement. This should prevent much of the noise.